# How give value to structures in c?

Tags: c, struct

I'm working with structures in `c`, but I can not give value to the structures' attributes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Book{
        char name[10];
        int id;
};

int main(){
        char tmp_name[10];
        int tmp_id;
        for(;;){
                struct Book a;
                scanf("%s",tmp_name);
                scanf("%d", tmp_id);
                strcpy(a.name,tmp_name);
                a.id = tmp_id;
                printf("name: %s\nid:%d", a.name, a.id);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This code compiles correctly but occurs `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

Comment: `for(;;)`...why you create an infinite loop?

Comment: `scanf("%d", tmp_id);` ==> `scanf("%d", &tmp_id);` or, even better, `if (scanf("%d", &tmp_id) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or even best, `char line[1000]; if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); if (sscanf(line, "%d", &tmp_id) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: ... and that has nothing in particular to do with structures.

Comment: `scanf("%s"` ==>  `scanf("%9s"` or better: use `fgets` instead of `scanf`

Comment: @pmg thanks, it worked. would you explain me the reason?

Comment: There's no need for `tmp_name` or `tmp_id`. `scanf("%d", &tmp_id);` ==> `scanf("%d",&(a.id));`

Comment: You need `&` to get the address expected by scanf's `"%d"`

Comment: We already have some thousands of "missing & in scanf" questions and none of them are particularly interesting to keep. Please just use the linked canonical dupe to close this FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> This code compiles correctly ...

In that case I'll strongly recommend that you increase the warning level of your compiler.

For instance "gcc -Wall code.c" may give you a warning like:

```
In function 'main':
warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   15 |                 scanf("%d", tmp_id);
      |                        ~^   ~~~~~~
      |                         |   |
      |                         |   int
      |                         int *
```

which tell you everything, i.e. **you pass an int to a function expecting an int pointer**

So just pass an int-pointer like:

```
scanf("%d", &tmp_id);
            ^
            Take address of tmp_id so that you have a pointer
```

BTW: for gcc you can use `-Werror` so that all warnings is treated as errors

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign value to struct. You don't need another variable.

```
struct Book a
scanf("%s", a.name);
scanf("%d", &a.id);
printf("name: %s\nid:%d", a.name, a.id);
```

Comment: The `scanf("%s", a.name)` offers no protections against a buffer overflow vulnerability, and is no different than the `gets` function, in this respect. `scanf("%9s", a.name)` must have been used instead.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", tmp_id);` has to be `scanf("%d", &tmp_id);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in by reference when using scanf.

```
        scanf("%s", tmp_name);
        scanf("%d", &tmp_id);
```

Comment: I think for `char` types there is no need to `&`.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi I agree, this way would make the beginners a wrong understanding of how C array really works. But I think it's not the "`char` types", it's the array.